# Delete all commits that I have pushed

Tags: git, git-commit, revert

I was on `branch1` and it has couple of commits that i did for `branch1`. After completing my task (and pushing those commits to remote). I switched to `branch2` from `branch1` with the following command

`git checkout -b branch2`

I intended to create it from `master` but I mistakenly created it from `branch1`

I made few changes in `branch2` and then commit/push to the remote by command `git push origin branch2`. Now when i look at remote repo, I see all of my `branch1` commits in the history of `branch2`.

Keep in mind that this was my first ever commit to `branch2` so i really don't care about all the earlier commits.

**P.S**

Some more background how branches are related.

I had some code which was in `master` branch (which we have decided to scrap). Now, I created a new branch `branch1`

```
> git status
> on branch master
> git checkout -b branch1
```

which has basic scaffolding of the project. This branch (once approved) will be merged (in this case over-write) the `master` branch. The `branch2` has db layer added on top. Theoretically it would be added on top of `branch1` but when i did so i saw that `branch2` has all the commits that I had in `branch1` that made me think that when we will merger `branch1` onto `master`, followed by `branch2` wouldn't it cause **double commits** history ? Thats the reason I wanted to delete the previous commits (which were borrowed from `branch1` to `branch2`).

Comment: From which branch/commit did you intend to create `branch2`?  Without knowing this, we can't give you a detailed answer on how to remedy your situation.

Comment: I updated my question. I wanted to create it from `master`

Comment: I gave you an answer.  If I knew better how `branch1` and `master` were related I could give other possibiliites, but for now I think `git cherry-pick` makes the most sense.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... added more detail

Comment: It won't cause double commits, or whatever you are thinking.  But it might make sense to have the db features be in a separate branch.

Answer (score 1):

When you did:

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

you created `branch2` on top of `branch1`.  This means that all the commits in `branch1` will be there, with the new commits you made to `branch2` being added on top of this.  Without knowing what the exact relationship is between `branch1` and `master`, the latter from which you really intended to create your branch, the safest way to correct the situation might be to cherry-pick the new commits from `branch2` onto a branch created from `master`:

```
git checkout branch2
git log
# observe and record the SHA-1 hashes of the commits you made

git checkout master
git checkout -b new_branch2

# now cherry-pick the commits from branch2 which you want to keep
git cherry-pick 2hie87jm8   # first commit
git cherry-pick j2cnd82ld   # second commit
# and so on for all commits, in the order you made them
```

Now you have your commits sitting on top of the correct branch.  You can delete `branch2` now via:

```
git branch -d branch2
```